# Is there a way to connect to a different host than localhost in application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a school assignment and have to hand in my application on a virtualbox machine. The MySQL on there isn't working so I am trying to connect my spring boot application to an online database instead of the one on localhost, but I am clueless what I should enter on the spring.datasource.url.

Current code:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smalleducator_db?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=CET
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

Does anyone know what I should enter at datasource.url to connect to my online database? I have a server IP, database name, username and password. I have tried:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:3306/smalleducator_db?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=CET
```

But I am getting this error:

````
Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null,  message from server: "Host '213.127.85.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server".```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are doing it right. It seems that your database is not configured for remote access. Make sure your port is open and you can access the database from remote (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) and then add the correct hostname or IP address to your configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://HOSTNAME_OR_IP:3306/smalleducator_db?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=CET
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```